# My AeroPlane Script is working but when turning it still goes the direction it was going

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a simple AeroPlane Script, but its turning but going in the direction it was going before.
heres the code.

```
public float speed;
public float minSpeed;
public float MaxSpeed;
public float DecreaseSpeed;
public float SpeedIncrease;
public Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.zero;
CharacterController characterController;

Rigidbody rb;


void Awake()
{
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(speed <= MaxSpeed && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed += SpeedIncrease;
    }
    
    if(speed >= 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        speed -= DecreaseSpeed;
    }
    
    if(speed >= minSpeed && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed -= Notspeedin;
    }
    
    

    moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, speed);
    characterController.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);

    if(speed >= minSpeed)
    {
            transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0, 0);
    }
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));

}
```

Its working, but not. Im a begginer btw. Any help is appreciated.

If you can, please share your script ^w^.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for, really. Can you describe what you want to achieve and what is the error which you are trying to fix?

Comment: its not an error, it wont change the direction even though the Airplane is facing somewhere else @hardartcore

Comment: Your ```moveDir``` is in local-space, but ```characterController.move()``` expects world-space.  You could do conversions, but probably simpler if you just use ```moveDir = transform.forward * speed;```